# Adding a navigation accessory to a UITableCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am learning about TableViews in Xcode right now and I am having trouble finding some info on TableViewCell accessories.

My goal is to have a MasterTableView and a SubTableView. When a MasterTableCell is tapped to take the user to the SubTableView. But I'm stuck with something simple like showing a '>' on the right side of the cell to show that it has a SubTableView.

Do I need to design my own button? I thought there was a navigation image already available to me in the UI storyboard maker but it won't let me drag and use it in my custom cell I'm making.

Any thoughts or links to documentation would be great. I've looked in the developer library and all it tells me is that it is possible, not how to do it.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a Prototype Cell in the Storyboard, just set the "Accessory" type in the Attributes inspector to "Disclosure Indicator".

If you create the cell programmatically, set

```
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
```

From the documentation:

> `UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator`
>   The cell has an accessory
>   control shaped like a chevron. This control indicates that tapping the
>   cell triggers a push action. The control does not track touches.

Comment: Thank you! That was exactly what I was looking for. I must have just had the name wrong too. I didn't know it was call a 'disclosure indicator'.